# What is the best way to reference the same path twice in a SwiftUI View?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I am trying to create a dynamically generated button that uses the same path to draw the primary shape and then draw the border. Full code below.

My current best approach calls the button generator twice, but because it uses random data (design constraint), the consecutive calls use different data and therefore the border does not correctly overlap the button shape. See the image below.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

class ButtonPath {
    func points(height: Int) ->
        ((Int,Int),(Int,Int),(Int,Int),
         (Int,Int),(Int,Int),(Int,Int),
         (Int,Int),(Int,Int),(Int,Int),
         (Int,Int),(Int,Int),(Int,Int))
    {
        func rand() -> Int { Int.random(in: -5...5) }
        func r2(x: Int) -> Int { Int.random(in: -x...x) }
        let screen: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let widthMx = CGFloat(0.9)
        let origin = (x:15, y:15)
        let width = Int(screen.width * widthMx)

        // Corner points
        let tl   = (x: origin.x + rand(),   y: origin.x + rand()) // tl = Top Left, etc.
        let tr   = (x: origin.x + width + rand(),      y: origin.y + rand())
        let bl   = (x: origin.x + rand(),   y: origin.y + height + rand())
        let br   = (x: origin.x + width + rand(),      y: origin.y + height + rand())

        // Arc controls, we're drawing a rectangle counter-clockwise from the top left
        let a1c1 = (x: origin.x + rand(),   y: Int(Double(origin.y+height+rand()) * 0.3)) // a1c1 = Arc 1 Control 1
        let a1c2 = (x: origin.x + rand(),   y: Int(Double(origin.y+height+rand()) * 0.6))
        let a2c1 = (x: Int(Double(origin.x+width+rand()) * 0.3), y: origin.y + height + rand())
        let a2c2 = (x: Int(Double(origin.x+width+rand()) * 0.6), y: origin.y + height + rand())
        let a3c1 = (x: origin.x + width + rand(),                y: Int(Double(origin.y + height+rand()) * 0.6))
        let a3c2 = (x: origin.x + width + rand(),                y: Int(Double(origin.y + height+rand()) * 0.3))
        let a4c1 = (x: Int(Double(origin.x+width+rand()) * 0.6), y: origin.y + rand())
        let a4c2 = (x: Int(Double(origin.x+width+rand()) * 0.6), y: origin.y + rand())

        return (
            t1: tl, tr: tr, b1: bl, br: br,
            a1c1: a1c1, a1c2: a1c2, a2c1: a2c1,
            a2c2:a2c2, a3c1:a3c1, a3c2:a3c2, a4c1:a4c1, a4c2:a4c2
        )
    }
    func path (height:Int) -> Path {
        let (tl, tr, bl, br, a1c1, a1c2, a2c1, a2c2, a3c1, a3c2, a4c1, a4c2) = points(height: height)
        let path1 = Path { path in
            path.move( to: CGPoint(x: tl.0, y: tl.1) )
            path.addCurve( to: CGPoint(x: bl.0, y: bl.1), control1: CGPoint(x: a1c1.0, y: a1c1.1), control2: CGPoint(x: a1c2.0, y: a1c2.1))
            path.addCurve( to: CGPoint(x: br.0, y: br.1), control1: CGPoint(x: a2c1.0, y: a2c1.1), control2: CGPoint(x: a2c2.0, y: a2c2.1))
            path.addCurve( to: CGPoint(x: tr.0, y: tr.1), control1: CGPoint(x: a3c1.0, y: a3c1.1), control2: CGPoint(x: a3c2.0, y: a3c2.1))
            path.addCurve( to: CGPoint(x: tl.0, y: tl.1), control1: CGPoint(x: a4c1.0, y: a4c1.1), control2: CGPoint(x: a4c2.0, y: a4c2.1))
        }
        return path1
    }
}

struct MyButton: View {
    var color: String
    var title: String
    var height: Int
    var path: (Path) {
        get { ButtonPath().path(height: height) }
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                path.fill(Color(color))
                path.stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4).shadow(color: Color("gray4"), radius: 4, x: -10, y: -10)
                Text(self.title).font(.custom("Chaloops-Bold", size: 30)).tracking(5).shadow(radius: 2)
            }
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .frame(height:130)
        }
    }
}

struct Button_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            MyButton(color: "red1", title: "SUBMIT", height: 100)
            MyButton(color: "blue1", title: "SUBMIT", height: 100)
            MyButton(color: "red1", title: "SUBMIT", height: 100)
            MyButton(color: "blue1", title: "SUBMIT", height: 100)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it can be done

Variant 1:

```
struct MyButton: View {
    var color: String
    var title: String
    var height: Int

    var body: some View {
        let path = ButtonPath().path(height: height)
        return VStack {
            ZStack {
                path.fill(Color(color))
                path.stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4).shadow(color: Color("gray4"), radius: 4, x: -10, y: -10)
                Text(self.title).font(.custom("Chaloops-Bold", size: 30)).tracking(5).shadow(radius: 2)
            }
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .frame(height:130)
        }
    }
}
```

Variant 2:

```
struct MyButton: View {
    var color: String
    var title: String
    var height: Int

    private let path: Path

    init(color: String, title: String, height: Int) {
        self.color = color
        self.title = title
        self.height = height
        self.path = ButtonPath().path(height: height)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                path.fill(Color(color))
                path.stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4).shadow(color: Color("gray4"), radius: 4, x: -10, y: -10)
                Text(self.title).font(.custom("Chaloops-Bold", size: 30)).tracking(5).shadow(radius: 2)
            }
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .frame(height:130)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Asperi! I've learned a lot from both of your variants I was able to remove my ugly hacks.